Unable to create CSS menu with submenus and animated underline on top level links
I am creating a Pure CSS menu.
The requirement is to have an animated underline appear on hover under the top level links (animated from center out).
I can find plenty of solutions for the animation online and all work when I am not using sub-menu items; Start CSS underline animation from center instead of left
However, I cannot seem to find a workable solution to allow a nested menu with animated underlines on the top level.
Is this possible using a list based menu with submenus?


html {
    font-family: "Outfit", sans-serif;
    font-optical-sizing: auto;
    font-size: 100%;
}

body {
    background-color: #E9E3D3;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    margin : 0;
    padding : 0;
}

nav#mainmenu {
    padding: 0px;
}

nav#mainmenu a {
    color: #000000;
    display:block;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav#mainmenu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav#mainmenu > ul > li {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

nav#mainmenu > ul > li:first-of-type{
    margin-left: 0px;
}

ul > li:last-of-type{
    margin-right: 0px;
}

/* Sub Menus */

nav#mainmenu li ul {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    display: none;
    margin-left: -10px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: absolute;
}

nav#mainmenu li:hover ul{
  display: block;
}

nav#mainmenu li ul li {
  display: block;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

nav#mainmenu li ul li a{
  font-weight: 400;
    color:#000000;
}

nav#mainmenu li ul li:hover {
    background-color: #00beee;
}

nav#mainmenu .menuexpandicon {
    top: 0px;
    fill: none;
    stroke-width: 2;
    stroke: #000000;
    margin: 0 0 2px 3px
}
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav id="mainmenu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Main Option1 <svg width="11" height="8" class ="menuexpandicon" viewBox="0 0 11 8"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M10 1.5L5.5 6.5L1 1.5" /></svg></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">sub option1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">sub option2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">sub option3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Main Option 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Main Option 3 <svg width="11" height="8" class ="menuexpandicon" viewBox="0 0 11 8"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M10 1.5L5.5 6.5L1 1.5" /></svg></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">sub option1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">sub option2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>



